# How to run a single test method in simpletest unittest class?

Tags: simpletest

This is my Unit Test class

```
<?
require_once '../simpletest/unit_tester.php';
require_once '../simpletest/reporter.php';
class Academic extends UnitTestCase
{
    function setUp()
    {
    }
    function tearDown()
    {                           
    }
    function testAc1()
    {          
    } 
    function testAc4()
    {         
    }     
    function testAc7()
    {        
    }

}

$test = new Academic();
$test->run(new HtmlReporter());
?>
```

When I run this script all methods viz., testAc1, testAc4, testAc7 etc are run.
 Is there a way to execute just a single method ?

Thanks,
Shikhar

Answer (score 3):

After digging through the SimpleTest source a bit, I have found the easiest way is to override the test's getTests() method as follows,

```
require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');

class Academic extends UnitTestCase
{
  # .. 
  function testAc7()
  {        
  }

  function getTests()
  {
    return array("testAc7");
  }
}
```

Here, simply including autorun.php as per usual, only the tests named in getTests() will be run.